# selenium python how to click any specific element of image box for loading all image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to be click on each dot for loading all images. I am trying to do this by for loop but didn't work. see the screenshot:
[image]

here is my code:

```
image_dot_click = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='Product__SlideshowNavDot']")

for i in image_dot_click:
    i.click()
```

getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='Product__SlideshowNavDot']"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

but I select the right xpath. see my console screenshot

[image]

which telling me my xpath selecting four element. how to click on each dot?

Comment: Is this image carousel is being created by JavaScript? If so, are you giving that JavaScript an opportunity to run before selecting the elements? We need to see the context of the code you provided

Comment: can you share the page link?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that:

a) The page isn't rendered yet.
b) The dots are not rendered yet.

```
# To fix a), you need to add a wait function which waits for the element to be available, and looks like this:

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

WebDriverWait(driver,6).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, ""//a[@class='Product__SlideshowNavDot']"")))

# To fix b), you need to scroll down the page for the dots to render

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 990000)") # Scrolls to the bottom of the page
```

Answer (score 0):

apply `xpath` `indexing` and loop through like this ":

```
no_of_buttons = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='Product__SlideshowNavDot']"))

i = 1
for button in range(no_of_buttons):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//a[@class='Product__SlideshowNavDot'])[{i}]").click()
    time.sleep(.5)
    i = i + 1
```